# How can I combine these two SQL queries into one?

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server 2005. Table schema is MarketdataID, Datatype, Date, Source, Coordinate, Value. PK is everything except Value. Data may be available from multiple sources and may not be available for the given date; I want to get the most recent date before the given date, and only one source per date.

```
SELECT top 1 [Source], [Date] FROM Market
WHERE MarketDataID = ?
AND DataType = ?
AND [Date] <= ?
order by [date] desc, [source]
```

then use the returned date and source in this query:

```
SELECT [Coordinate], [Value] FROM Market
WHERE MarketDataID = ?
AND DataType = ?
AND [Date] = ?
AND [Source] = ?
ORDER BY [coordinate]
```

Comment: which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: Unclear what you are trying to do - you can't just "combine" the sql statements. What output are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Is your second query meant to use the output from the first?

Comment: What output are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @RedFilter I think you're on to something. It looks like what he's really asking is how to get the highest source/date combo (as directed in query 1) and use that as parameters to query 2. Unfortunately I don't know a good way to do that.

Comment: Thanks RedFilter and ean5533 for being able to read my mind and clarify what I was really asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT [Coordinate], [Value]
  FROM Market AS m0
  JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 m2.[Source], m2.[Date], m2.MarketDataID, m2.DataType
          FROM Market AS m2
         WHERE m2.MarketDataID = ?
           AND m2.DataType = ?
           AND m2.[Date] <= ?
           ORDER BY m2.[Date] DESC, m2.[Source]
       ) AS m1
    ON m0.[Source]     = m1.[Source]
   AND m0.[Date]       = m1.[Date]
   AND m0.MarketDataID = m1.MarketDataID
   AND m0.DataType     = m1.DataType
 ORDER BY [coordinate]
```

Comment: I think this may be it, as long as the `join (select ... )` works in SQL Server 2005.